# How to add a VF page to Event standard pagelauout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, event

Is it is possible to add a Vf page to Event standard page layout. If it is possible please tell me, how can i do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easy, just follow this steps:

1) First create a new Visualforce page. Go to **`Setup`** - **`Develop`** - **`Pages`** and click on the `New` button. For `standrard controller` select `Event`. Save the page:

[image]

2) Now go to the standard event **`page layout`** and edit it:

[image]

3) Over there in the **`Visualforce Pages`** area find your page. But insert a **new section** first. Then just drag and drop your page to this section and save the layout:

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see "Visualforce Pages" link on page layout. Do I need to enable something?

Comment: @doga If there is no page where the standard controller for this object is defined - the "Visualforce Page" link is not shown.

Comment: @mast0r i am getting the page but only after the record get saved i actually need it on creation.

Comment: @mast0r The VF page would be visible only on edit not while creation of a new event?

Comment: @AnuRaj I think it is not possible to see inserted page(s) on the edit or create layouts :(

Comment: My issue, I only can see the inline vf page in Detail but when I preview as Edit I could not see it.Anyone got this issue?

Comment: @unidha It is not an issue, it is OK.You can not use inline visualforce on the edit pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a visualforce page using standard controller 'Event' and then include it as an inline visualforce page from your Event pagelayout.

Comment: can you please check it out their is no option to create a Vf page in Pagelayout of event.