# Can I add a custom message at the top of a page based on some criteria?

Tags: apex, page-layout, master-detail

Our tech support team uses cases for interacting with customers.  Based on some criteria on the parent account, we are looking for a way to show a message to our tech support team indicating that this account is special.

I could go down the route of adding new fields, formulas and workflows; My hesitation is that the data already exists so this would result in duplicate data simply to meet this requirement.

I'm comfortable with Apex as I've written a handful of triggers, but, I have never tried something like this before so I thought I would seek input from the community.

Comment: When you want to show the message, on delete or on detail page when someone view it.

Comment: @responsive - On the detail page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need apex at all!

1. Create a new visualforce page with a standard controller based on your object
2. In this page create an apex:pageMessage
3. Set render criteria basen on some field
4. Add this page to the object layout

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
           sidebar="false"
           showHeader="false"
           showChat="false">

<apex:pageMessage summary="This pageMessage for the supporter" 
                  severity="warning" 
                  strength="3"
                  rendered="{!Account.Name = 'Hello'}" />
</apex:page>
```

Now go to the page layout and put a new section to the page, set a height to the 50px ([you can read here about how to insert a page to the layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/how-to-add-a-vf-page-to-event-standard-pagelauout)):

[image]

Put this visualforce page to the section and save the layout:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help so far.  I should have been a little more clear.  Can I access the parent account from the case Visual Force page to determine if it has any related records on a different object?  The data I need doesn't exist on the case itself unfortunately.

Comment: @Ek0nomik Hmm, i think you need a controller extension for this case.

Comment: Thanks!  I read through the documentation and created a controller extension and that did the trick.

Comment: Awesome answer! Pity I can't upvote same answer multiple times :)

Comment: Hi @SergeyUtko - this is a great answer and has partially solved my problem also...  I have added the VisualFlow component on the page layout of my object which works fine - my question is how do I make the same message appear on the the 'edit' state of the same object (e.g. if it showing on an Accounts it needs to show when editing that account also - i.e. before you press 'save') Thanks

Comment: @SergeyUtko I have also used this page for help (hoping that the edit page under the section properties was going to work) but nothing... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68405/embed-a-visualforce-page-in-a-standard-edit-layout