# Embed a Visualforce page in a Standard Edit Layout

Tags: visualforce, page-layout, pagelayoutassignment

I needed to output some text on a custom object and managed to do so by embedding the following VF in the Custom Layout:

```
<apex:page standardController="Standard_Controller__c">
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style=" height: 50%;">
                <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic" value="Test">
    </apex:outputText>
            </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

However, the same VF does not appear in the standard *edit* page layout. Does it mean that this is not possible?

Thanks,

I.

Answer (score 3):

Hi this has been delivered in Summer 16'. See [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br8CAAS) for
reference.

[image]

Comment: Please note that this is not a social media site. We do not use hash tags here, and they do absolutely nothing to improve content.

Comment: I see a comment that it is only released for lightning. Actual release notes would be a much more logical link.

Comment: Received feedback from @AskSalesforce on twitter that this is Partially Delivered. And what that Partially is not clear.

Comment: @anupprakashh this is partially delivered in summer 16 https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br8CAAS … Thanks! ^RG

Comment: Is there any updates on this? It can only be done in Lightning still, correct?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

So this feature apparently is not available, but you can vote for it on the ideas exchange [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS). It is potentially on the product management team's roadmap.

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

It sounds like VisualForce is overkill for your use case, but regardless your question here is about how to embed a `VisualForce Page` in an Edit `Page Layout`.

First, begin editing your Layout. Click `VisualForce Pages` - `Section`.

[image]

Once you have added a `Section`, you will be prompted to give it a `Name` and specify if it should be displayed on the `Detail Page` as well as the `Edit Page`. Make sure `Edit Page` is checked.

[image]

If you click the little wrench icon in the top right to edit its properties. You can want to go back and add this option to an existing section, hover on the header and you will see a little wrench icon that will bring the dialog back up.

[image]

Comment: are you sure?  OP asked for VF page embedded in Standard Edit page -- I can only get VF pages to appear on Standard Detail pages

Comment: Huh, I guess I always assumed that checkbox did what it purported to do. It is potentailly on the roadmap...https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br8CAAS.

Comment: if it were possible, then overriding the Edit button would be used less frequently.  at least this idea has a shot at happening unlike most of mine :-(

Comment: @AdrianLarson tried to do this yesterday - do you know why it isn't working for me? is it because the edit instance is something hard coded in SF and cannot be modified - unless you override the whole edit button functionality?

Answer (score 1):

2020 update about the current feature gap between lightning/LEX and Classic:

Please vote for  https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000PkZqQAK
to help prioritize adding support for embedded/inline visualforce/components  in Classic:

The concept is currently only available in Lightning/LEX per https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br8CAAS

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention, this was an old question and since then I moved (gladly)  away from SF, but it is nice to know that things are progressing towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

add a section on the Standard_Controller__c object page layout and pull this page into it. It will displayed on detaile page. But when you click edit (I mean on edit page you can not see it)

Comment: are you saying that there is no way to display it when editing the page? Thanks.

Comment: If you replicate the standard page on a vf page you can show that custom Vf part which you are willing to show. If not my answer to your question is YES.

Comment: I believe he's saying that the only way to display the VF markup you provided above is to completely recreate the standard edit page using the standard controller, and add in your code as well. Visualforce pages added into a page layout do not display on edit.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Suri's solution, you could also create a field on the object with your value, then display it as locked. Would need to know more about what you want to display before you do this.

Comment: thanks for this. I will only need to display a fairly simple textual information that needs to be visible on the Std edit layout, too. I have forgotten to mention that my custom object is actually a record type - does this open up for other potential ways to display the text?

Comment: You mean your custom object has one or more recordtypes? That doesn't impact anything. I would create a custom field to display your text and add it to the layout. Note that formula fields are not displayed in edit mode, so just create a text field with your value as the default, and then lock it on the layout. 

Another option that might serve well here is to put your text into a section header on the layout. Make sure to make it viewable on edit.

Comment: thanks once again. I have tried to create a Text custom field and assigned the default value of "This is my text", then made it READ-ONLY. Although i can see on the edit page, it expects a user input and does not output the default value. Am i missing anything?

Comment: Default values are only set when a new record is created. You will need to use the dataloader (or Jitterbit, Demand Tools, etc) to set the value for all existing records. 

This is the advantage of putting your text in the Section Header on the page layout - it automatically populates on all records, though it is a little easier to miss from a user's POV.

Also, as a System Administrator, you have the ability to edit all fields regardless of whether they are locked on the layout. Log in as a user to make sure the "lock" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding a VF page in edit mode can be done only for lightning and not in classic.
Another option could be, create a custom VF page, use [Fieldset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm) from Salesforce and standard controller to get similar functionality and embed your VF page over there.