# Advice in adding Web Service functionality to Salesforce pages

Tags: webservices, service-cloud-console

I am hoping someone can advise...

This is our plan/setup; We use "Service Cloud" to handle cases, we have record types to determine the right layouts for the case.  This is expanding rapdily with eventually the plan for 50 or so Record Types as we include more and more of our organisations case types.  Originally we had hoped to simply use Page Layouts and standard functionality to ease the process...

A new requirement is to include an Address Lookup for the Contacts and multiple address lookups for the case (1 case can impact up to 4 addresses).  This Address lookup simply calls a Web Service to validate and return 8 address fields.  Unfortunately we couldn't find an App on the AppExchange to do this.  Initially we started writing VisualForce pages to introduce this functionality via the web (and this works fine via Javascript/Jquery) but now we have to turn our attention to the Salesforce Staff and I am a little lost.

Essentially I see us having these options:

- Custom Visualforce pages for everything utilising the same Javscript/Jquery lookups as the web forms.  This would require quite a lot of work as each record type would require it's own visualforce page and we would need custom navigation to open the necessary visualforce pages per case...
- Part Page embedded visualforce page with a controller extension to map the fields between the standard object and embedded page (is this possible)?
- Custom Object Lookup ...except I don't know how as the Web Service access millions of records and we can't store those in Salesforce.
- Some other solution

I wasn't sure where else to enquire as writing Visualforce pages for all of the existing functionality...seems...daunting (Contact object pages, case object pages and it's associated record types - up to 60...:()

I really appreciate any advice.  So far Salesforce has exceeded our expectations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't advise creating 50 record types, as they are difficult to manage and if you make a change you have to potentially do it 50 times. I see a benefit looking into your business processes and see if you can find a common denominator between the various cases.

In terms of your original query, you can embedded a visual force page into a standard page layout. That visual force page should have a visual force component which will have the JS capable to do a request to your server. Bear in mind that the JS will run client side, so that means you are less likely to encounter problems if you have the address solution in-house.

You could also have the component having it's own controller which can a generic function that will handle all types of cases.

Comment: Thanks,  I'll look into embedding a visualforce page into the standard page.  I assume with the extension controller we can pass values to and fro?  For example we would need to pass the address fields at least.

Comment: I don't see how we can get away from a lot of record types, we must have 10 or so depts and each of those departments have x amount of "case types" with each case type including multiple custom  fields - ill have a think.

Comment: What is the reason of having different case types per department ? Is it because of certain people from a certain department have access to a certain case type ? If that's so, you could do some field level security or data segregation

Comment: It isn't so much user access as a dept's function.  Each dept obviously has their responsibilities and each of the record types relate to a specific function to be completed by someone (or a group of people) in that dept.  Each function will have a different workflow and in most cases x amount of unique fields (we are not-for-profit so we only use Service Cloud..not interested in the Sales pipeline.)  For example one department, Waste, will have Record types in salesforce for "missed collection", "new bin", "broken bin" and each of these has a unique process/workflow and field requirement.

Comment: I am getting there with the part page visualforce component. It is visible on the edit/detail section but not on "New Case"? Is it possible to display a visualforce embedded page on the "New Case"? layout (under Page Layout it is ticked for Edit,Detail).  Guessing it means re-writing the "New" case page...

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68405/embed-a-visualforce-page-in-a-standard-edit-layout. You basically put the visualforce component or page within a section and that section has the ability to be displayed on edit page.

Comment: Yeah I've got that part (actually looking ok - surprised!) but I assume it isn't possible to also include it on a "New" record layout (only edit/detail). Thanks

Comment: 'Edit' layout is the 'New' layout. You only have two option edit or detail. The edit mode supports both 'New' and the actual 'Edit'

Comment: Ahhh confusing!!!  I have definately ticked that so I guess I have ran into a wall displaying a visualforce page in new/edit...some people on ur link suggests it isn't possible...it is a page in this instance, not a component.  I appreciate the patient help :D