# Embed visualforce page to existing layout

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I am new to the salesforce and I want to do the same thing that this guys want to do: [Embed a Visualforce page in a Standard Edit Layout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68405/embed-a-visualforce-page-in-a-standard-edit-layout)

But on the left side I am not able to see "Visual Force Pages" see below screenshot
[image]

I have added section by selecting from the left side 'Fields' and then 'Section' and here is the screenshot that I have added section:
[image]

Inside "Contact's Personal Data" I want to display Visualforce view that I have created.

How to enable or see the Visualforce page on the left side and add view that I have created through visualforce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have created a visualforce page having a **standard controller**(In your case, it would be equal to Contact), You will start viewing Visualforce option in left-hand side on top of the page layout editor.

> Page layout editor does not show visualforce option until you don't
> have to add anything on the page.

Or if you are in Lightning and want to use Visualforce page that does not have Standard Controller, You can use Visualforce component in Lightning App builder. Note:- You visualforce should be enabled for using in Lightning.

[image]