# Display custom message using Visualforce depending on custom field criteria

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

I have used the answer to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16271/can-i-add-a-custom-message-at-the-top-of-a-page-based-on-some-criteria) question on Stack exchange to create a message to display on my custom object.

What do I need to add to it to only display the message if a certain condition in my object is met e.g. a custom field checkbox is selected, a certain name appears, date is older than 1 month... ect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing the same example you can use `rendered` attribute with `<apex:outputpanel>`

```
<apex:page standardController="Account"
           sidebar="false"
           showHeader="false"
           showChat="false">
<apex:outputpanel id="message">
 <apex:pageMessage rendered="{!object.checkbox_field__c}"
                  summary="This pageMessage for the supporter" 
                  severity="warning" 
                  strength="3"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

In case you need to show message on checkbox check, then you will need to `rerender` the id `message` which in `outputpanel`

Comment: Thanks @ashwani but it comes with the following message "Error: Attribute "rendered" was already specified for element "apex:pagemessage"."  I basically only want the message to display if the checkbox is 'ticked'....

Comment: @user2326637 oh! it is declared twice. I am updating the answer.  Remove this `rendered="{!Account.Name = 'Hello'}"`

Comment: PERFECT!!! - Also you need a '>' at the end of </apex:outputpanel>!!!

Comment: Yes! updated the answer.