# Showing Products in a related list at the Account level

Tags: visualforce

My organization would like to show a related list of all of the Products associated with closed won Opportunities linked to a given Account at the Account level. Essentially if Product X is linked to Opportunity Y, and Opp Y is linked to Account Z, we'd like a related list at the Account level displaying Product X. I've already created embedded charts for this, but the team making the request is insistent that they get this in the form of line items. I know that it should be possible to code a Visualforce Page Related List for this, but I don't even know where to start with coding that. Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: Are duplicates okay, or not? If duplicates are allowed, just create a custom lookup field from the opportunity line item object to the account directly, and populate it with a trigger. No Visualforce, just a little bit of extra coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a custom `Account__c` lookup on your `Opportunity Product`, **you can implement this entire solution without using any `Apex`.** There are four discrete steps, described in more detail below.

1. Create the lookup.
2. Add the `Related List` to your `Page Layout(s)`.
3. Update child `OpportunityLineItem` records when an `Opportunity` changes its `StageName`.

   - If it becomes `Closed Won`, set the lookups.
   - If it is no longer `Closed Won`, clear the lookups.
4. If an `OpportunityLineItem` is added to an `Opportunity` that is already `Closed Won`, set the lookup.

---

**Lookup**

Add a lookup to the `Opportunity Product` object. Make sure to set the child relationship name to `ClosedWonProducts`.

---

**Related List**

You can actually just use an OOB `Related List` in the `Page Layout`. If you want, though, you can still do it via `Visualforce`. Just remember to [KISS](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/20262/keep-it-simple-stupid-principle-kiss-principle):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="ClosedWonProducts">
</apex:page>
```

---

**Opportunity Trigger**

Actually syncing the lookup is a little bit more work, but nothing too crazy. Don't be intimidated by the number of steps below, I got very specific. It should take you long to use `Process Builder` to create a flow as follows:

1. Navigate to `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Process Builder`.
2. Click <kbd>New</kbd>.
   Fill in `Process Name` > `Closed Won Opportunity`.
   No need to fill in `API Name`, it will auto-populate.
   You may fill in an optional `Description`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
3. Click <kbd>+ Add Object</kbd>.
   Select `Opportunity`.
   Select `Start the process` > `when a record is created or edited`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>+ Add Criteria</kbd>.
   Fill in `Criteria Name` > `Enter Closed Won`.
   Select `Conditions are met`.

   Select `Field` > `Stage`.
   Select `Operator` > `Is Changed`.
   Select `Value` > `True`.

   Select `Field` > `Stage`.
   Select `Operator` > `Equals`.
   Select `Value` > `Closed Won`.

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
5. Click <kbd>+ Add Action</kbd>.
   Select `Action Type` > `Update Records`.
   Fill in `Action Name` > `Set Product Accounts`.

   Choose `Select a record related to the Opportunity`.
   Select `OpportunityLineItems`.

   Select `Field` > `Account`.
   Select `Type` > `Reference`.
   Select `Value` > `Opportunity ID >` > `AccountId`.

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
6. Click <kbd>+ Add Criteria</kbd>.
   Fill in `Criteria Name` > `Leave Closed Won`.
   Select `Conditions are met`.

   Select `Field` > `Stage`.
   Select `Operator` > `Is Changed`.
   Select `Value` > `True`.

   Select `Field` > `Stage`.
   Select `Operator` > `Does not equal`.
   Select `Value` > `Closed Won`.

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
7. Click <kbd>+ Add Action</kbd>.
   Select `Action Type` > `Update Records`.
   Fill in `Action Name` > `Unset Product Accounts`.

   Choose `Select a record related to the Opportunity`.
   Select `OpportunityLineItems`.

   Select `Field` > `Account`.
   Select `Type` > `ID`.
   Select `Value` > `000000000000000`. (See: [Setting lookup field to blank using Process Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73707/setting-lookup-field-to-blank-using-process-builder))

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
8. Click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

---

**Opportunity Product Trigger**

One last use case, someone might add an `OpportunityLineItem` to an `Opportunity` that is already `Closed Won`.

1. Navigate to `Create` > `Workflows & Approvals` > `Process Builder`.
2. Click <kbd>New</kbd>.
   Fill in `Process Name` > `Closed Won Product`.
   No need to fill in `API Name`, it will auto-populate.
   You may fill in an optional `Description`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
3. Click <kbd>+ Add Object</kbd>.
   Select `Opportunity Product`.
   Leave `Start the process` > `only when a record is created`.
   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
4. Click <kbd>+ Add Criteria</kbd>.
   Fill in `Criteria Name` > `Is Closed Won`.
   Select `Conditions are met`.

   Select `Field` > `Opportunity ID >` > `Stage`.
   Select `Operator` > `Equals`.
   Select `Value` > `Closed Won`.
5. Click <kbd>+ Add Action</kbd>.
   Select `Action Type` > `Update Records`.
   Fill in `Action Name` > `Set Account`.

   Choose `Select the OpportunityLineItem record that started your process`.
   Select `Field` > `Account`.
   Select `Type` > `Reference`.
   Select `Value` > `Opportunity ID >` > `AccountId`.

   Click <kbd>Save</kbd>.
6. Click <kbd>Activate</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! I made a couple of small modifications, but it seems to be working.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help. Clicks not code! @C.Malloy

Answer (score 0):

Create a visualforce page and add it to your page layouts

I haven't tested the below code, so you might need to do some adjustments :)

VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ProductsListController" showHeader="false">

    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="/soap/ajax/26.0/apex.js"/>



    <apex:pageMessages />


    <apex:form >
    <apex:actionPoller action="{!refreshContext}" rerender="CustomList" interval="5" />



        <apex:pageblock id="CustomList"  Title="Products">         


        <apex:facet name="header">
           <div class="pbHeader">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pbTitle">                               
                                <h3 >Products</h3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </apex:facet>

            <div style="height: 200px; overflow-y:auto; display:{!IF(ContentAvailable==false,'none','block')}">
            <!-- VERSION JFO -->
            <table class="list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="headerRow">
                    <th class="actionColumn" scope="col" width="30%">Product Name</th>
                    <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col" width="20%">Last Modified</th>
                    <th class=" zen-deemphasize" scope="col" width="50%" >Wtv</th> 
                    </tr>


                    <!--Products -->
                     <apex:repeat var="prod" value="{!products}">
                        <tr class="dataRow even ">

                            <td> <a href ="" onclick="OpenMethod('{!prod.Id}');return false;"  style="color:black; cursor: pointer;text-decoration: underline;"> {!prod.Name} </a> </td>
                            <td> {!prod.LastModifiedDate}</td>
                            <td>wtv </td>

                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat> 



                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

        <apex:outputLabel value="No records to display" rendered="{!ContentAvailable==false}" styleClass="noRowsHeader">
         </apex:outputLabel>   
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

ApexClass:

```
public with sharing class  ProductsListController 
{

    public list<Product2 > products {get; set;}

    public Account acc {get;set;}

    public boolean contentAvailable  {get; set;}

    public ProductsListController (ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        try
        {
            controller.addFields(new list<String>{'id'});

            this.acc = (Account)controller.getRecord();
            loadProducts();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {

       }
    }

     private void loadProducts()
     {
        try
        {
            //do query here 
           products = [Select Id, (Id, Name From Products)
            From Opportunity
            Where where AccountID: accId];


            //flag to show products section
            if(products.size()>0)
                contentAvailable= true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }

    public PageReference refreshContext() 
    {
        loadProducts();
        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you decide for the coding, here is a very simple example for you. It is using a standard Account controller and a simple extension with a SOQL query that reads a data.

It will display all related opportunities with all related products like this:

```
Account
- Opp1
  - Product1
- OppX
  - ProductX
```

Here you can read how to add a visualforce page to the Account layout: [How to add a VF page to Event standard pagelauout](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9179/how-to-add-a-vf-page-to-event-standard-pagelauout/9181#9181)

Visualforce page:

```visualforce
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opps}" var="opp">
            <!-- Opportunity Header -->
            <apex:column value="{!opp.Name}" />
            <!-- related Products -->
            <apex:column breakBefore="true">
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Products" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opp.Products}" var="product">
                        <apex:column value="{!product.Name}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:pageblockSection>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
<apex:page>
```

Extension:

```apex
public class MyExtension {
    private final Account acct;
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.acct = (Account)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    // You should use your real Product2 relationship name (here just example with name Products)
    public List<Product2> getProducts() {
        return [Select Id, Name, (Id, Name From Products)
                From Opportunity
                Where AccountId = : acct.Id]
    }
}
```